# Why is variable displaying 0?

Tags: java, oop, variables, methods

This is my first time using StackOverflow so sorry if my question is nooby as I am learning Java. What I am trying to do now is pass a variable from one method into another method(same class) so I can show the value in a graph. My code is below:

**Method 2**

```
private void Average(){

        System.out.println(openessAverage);
        DefaultCategoryDataset bc = new DefaultCategoryDataset();                                                       
        bc.setValue(openessAverage, "Percentage", "Openess"); //Show here 

        JFreeChart jchart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Big 5 Graph", "ID","Percentage" , bc, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false ); //chart
        CategoryPlot plot = jchart.getCategoryPlot();
        ChartFrame chartFRM = new ChartFrame("Personality Insight", jchart,true);  
        chartFRM.setVisible(true);
        chartFRM.setSize(800,600); //Sets JFrame size
  }
```

When I run that code it gives me 0.0 in the console and graph is also 0. Any idea why? would really appreciate the help:)

Comment: Well it's possible that `PersonalityGraph()` has not been called yet.

Comment: But I thought you would not need to call it because its in the same class.

Comment: This is actually a good opportunity for you to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  This *will* be your most valuable tool as a programmer.  When you use an IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.) you can run your program in debug mode and literally step through the code, line by line, as it executes each line.  You can pause on any line, examine the runtime values of your variables, and generally observe the logical progression of the program.  When you do this, where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What are the runtime values of the relevant variables?

Comment: If no one calls it, being in the same class makes no difference.  Put a `println` in the `PersonalityGraph()` method that prints out when the method is executed.  If it never prints, then the problem is it's never being called.

Answer (score 2):

the reason is pretty simple

dividing integers will return an integer too. 
therefore

```
double c = a/b;
```

will be zero if `b > a`

**solution:** cast one of the operands to double

```
double c = (double)a/b
```

Answer (score 0):

The probelm has to do with the fact that you are dividing a double by an integer. Any time you do that, basically Java truncates the result (removes the decimal). In your case, the size of the list is probably greater than what it's dividing, so it's rounding down to 0.  To fix this, you can either cast opennes.size() to a double, or better, just cast that operation to a double.

Double num = (double) num1/num2;

Hope that helps